# Narrowing generic function parameters for methods in a nested object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a generic function that takes a key of the below example api as a first param, the name of a method of the nested object with that key as the second param and the parameters of that method as the third param

```
const api = {
    message: {
        post(message: string) {
            return 'success'
        }
    },
    events: {
        get(id: number) {
            return ['event']
        }
    }

}
```

I can narrow down the methods based on the key given in the first param, as so:

```
type API = typeof api;

function createRequest<T extends keyof API, K extends keyof API[T]>(key: T, method: K) {

}
```

Now if I try to call that function, after passing "message" as the first param, Typscript will only allow me to pass "post" as the second param. So far so good. But when I try to narrow down the parameters of the method as the third parameter to the createRequest function I'm getting stuck, I have tried what seemed logical:

```
function createRequest<T extends keyof API, K extends keyof API[T]>(key: T, method: K, params: Parameters<API[T][K]>[0]) {

}
```

Typescript shows an error for API[T][K] and it doesn't seem to be satisfied that K is indeed a keyof API[T] - it shows for example that:

```
Type 'API[T][string]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any
```

I can't really find a related answer, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You might be wondering why I would need to do this - why not just call the functions directly!? The bigger picture is I’m setting up a redux middleware for making API calls. I want to make the middleware generic and have it watching for a single dispatch action, the payload of which contains the instructions for what to do before making the api request, what api request to make and the params to pass into it, and what to do with the result of the api call. So this is the first step in building an action creator that takes the api method and params as the payload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a quirk in the compiler to me, might even be worth raising a github issue. The type parameter restraint for `T` in `Parameters` appears to be widening the index type for some reason.

If you get rid of it then it works as expected. I don't think you lose anything in type safety either because trying to access non-functions will still make it uncallable:

```
const api = {
  message: {
    post(message: string) {
      return "success";
    },
  },
  events: {
    get(id: number) {
      return ["event"];
    },
    noFunc: 42,
  },
};

type API = typeof api;

type WideParameters<T> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;

function createRequest<T extends keyof API, K extends keyof API[T]>(
  key: T,
  method: K,
  params: WideParameters<API[T][K]>[0],
) {
  return {} as any;
}

createRequest("events", "get", 1); 
  // OK
createRequest("events", "noFunc"); 
  // An argument for 'params' was not provided.
createRequest("events", "noFunc", "") 
  // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Comment: To complete your answer, you can add `type Return<T> = T extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : never;` and make the return type of `createRequest` something like `Return<API[T][K]>`